# MS Excel to Database

Tags: database, excel, powershell

I am searching for a way to transfer an Excel file to a database (the client is called mbox. Is there a general way to transfer Excel to a database?). At least I want a script writing the INSERT-commands for me. I tried it with PowerShell but run into one huge problem: I can't write a proper for-each-loop for this task:

```
if($Args.count -eq 0){ 
    "No Parameter-Error"
    exit
}
if($Args.count -gt 1){
    "Too many Parameter-Error"
    exit
}
if (-not (Test-path $args[0] -include *.csv)){
    "Invaild Root or no csv-file"
    exit
}
$spalten=Import-Csv $args[0] -Delimiter ";"
$spalten.GetEnumerator() | % {
    $key=$($_.key);
   Echo "$key"
   Echo $($_.value[$key])+"`n";
}
```

Please help, also know that I have no idea what one column will be named.

Comment: Is this an Excel file (.XLS,.XLSX,.XLSM) or a Comma Separated Value file (.CSV)? If it is a CSV, then this should be simple. Also, go ask Google about powershell script parameters and read up on them. You sir are re-creating parameters the hard way. What is your ForEach (alias %) loop supposed to accomplish, I don't understand the purpose of it.

Comment: It is csv. I googled and didn't find anything, because I want my script to work with different files, so I can't use $_.SpecificColocumName but rather use something like $_.key1 and $_.value1 and so on. In the end the loop should write my INSERT-Commands (like "INSERT INTO $args[0] $_.key1, $_.key2, ... VALUES ($_.value1, $_.value2, ...);") at best it writes it to a file.